# Array of strings sorting

Tags: swift, tableview

**How to sort the array of strings the simple way?**

```
var table = ["item1" ,"item2" ,"item3" ,"item4" , ... ]
```

Comment: This is not a `tableView`, it's an array of strings...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**If you want to sort it alphabetically**, then call a function **`sort()`** after your `var table = [...]`

```
var table = ["item1" ,"item2" ,"item3" ,"item4" , ... ]
sort()
```

And place the function (which you can update with many different options)

```
func sort() {
    table.sort(by: {$0.sort < $1.sort})
}
```

---

**The simplest way is to use `table.sort()` only**

```
var table = ["item1" ,"item2" ,"item3" ,"item4" , ... ]
table.sort()
```

---

Read the Apple Developer Documentation for **[sort()](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array/1688499-sort)**

Comment: How can I sort the table in reverse ?

Comment: Just replace `sort(by: {$0 < $1}` with `sort(by: {$0 > $1}`